# Java: Print all arraylist elements

Tags: java, arraylist

how to display all the arraylist elements using for loop, my code are look like below:

```
ArrayList<String[]> theRecord = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(strSQL);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

while(rs.next())
{
    String[] row = new String[columnCount];
    for (int i=0; i <columnCount ; i++)
    {
       row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
    }
    theRecord.add(row);
}
```

i want to loop the **theRecord** and get all its element by rows and columns.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: You need a compound loop, the outer loop looping of `theRecord` and the inner loop looping of each `String[]` within `theRecord`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: nothing wrong with the code, i just need to display out the arraylist element to manipulate it later on other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Iterator<String[]> iter = theRecord.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
   String[] temp = iter.next(); 
   for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
       //manipulate temp[i]
   }
}
```

or another example :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ListString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] str = new String[2];
        str[0] = "a";
        str[1] = "b";

        List<String[]> val = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        val.add(str);

        for(String[] s:val){
            for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                System.out.println(s[i]);
            }
        }

    }

 }
```

Output of latter is 
a
b

Hope that helps.

Comment: i replaced the getIterator with listIterator, now work fine with me, getIterator  method not found for me

Comment: My Bad !! it's just theRecord.iterator() or listIterator that you tried.... i wrote that piece trying to recall stuff. For the second half I actually wrote code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access each element of the ArrayList by using the method `ArrayList.get(int index)`.

In this case you'll use this to iterate over the List's elements:

```
for(int i = 0; i < theRecord.size(); i++){
// Run over the elements in the List
for(int j = 0; j < theRecord.get(i).length(); j++)
// Run over the element itself. Through the indexes of the element Array.
// And do whatever you want with it
}
```